# How to mount a Veracrypt volume on FreeBSD?

Tags: mount, freebsd, veracrypt

When I mount a volume (stored on external USB drive) on Linux I get the following error

```bash
> sudo veracrypt --text --mount /path-to-volume /mnt --pim 0  --keyfiles "" --slot 1 --protect-hidden no --verbose

Enter password for /path-to-volume:

Error: mount: /mnt: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/veracrypt1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

The volume is OK, because I can mount it on `FreeBSD` (where the volume was created).

```bash
# Linux
> veracrypt -t --version
VeraCrypt 1.25.9
```

Partition Type
`NTFS`

Any hint? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've made it.
The key to understand what's happend was to create 2 brand new VeraCrypt volumes.

1. one on Linux
2. one on FreeBSD

During the creation I noticed that Veracrypt offers different filesystems based on systems

1. Linux supports all sorts of file systems (ext2, ext3, exFAT, etc.)
2. FreeBSD supports only UFS

Knowing that, on Linux I mount the volume without filesystem and then mount it as UFS.

So the commands in my case are

```bash
sudo veracrypt --text --mount /volume-path /mount-path --filesystem=none --pim 0  --keyfiles "" --slot 1 --protect-hidden no --verbose
# then mount ufs, like on https://askubuntu.com/questions/85154/mount-ufs-filesystem 
sudo modprobe ufs
sudo mount -r -t ufs -o ufstype=ufs2 /dev/mapper/veracrypt1 /mount-destiny
```

The `/dev/mapper/veracrypt1` path I got from Gnome-disks application, but there must be some other way too.